# How to convert hexadecimal to binary

Tags: c

What's the representation of `0x2b` in binary? And how to convert it ? Im a little confused about **b**.

```
char a = 0x2b;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The`0x`part means the following number is in hexadecimal notation.

Since in hex, `0x10 == 16` and `0xb = 11`, we have:

```
0x2B = 0x20 + 0xB = 32 + 11 = 43
```

So `0x2B` is`43`in decimal (the system we commonly use), and that's

```
101011
```

in binary.

To clarify, no matter what notation you use (decimal or hexadecimal) to declare/overwrite variables in C, the result is the same.

```
char a = 0x2B;
char b = 43;
if (a == b)
    printf("But of course they're the same!\n");
else
    printf("This should not happen\n");
```